# PrimeFaces dataExport with lazy model return empty PDFs

Tags: primefaces, itext, primefaces-datatable, java-21, primefaces-dataexporter

I am using prime faces 13, with java 21 and the `com.lowgie.itext` v2.1.7 (It is the last one supported by prime faces).

The thing is that I can import my data correctly into others formats like `cvs` or `xls`, but it could be great to have the option of exporting a little section of users to pdf as well.

When I export my data as a pdf file, a pdf is downloaded but it is empty (0 Bytes file), and there is no error.

Here is my code:

```html
<p:commandButton value="Export">
   <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="table-id" fileName="myExportedPdf"/>
</p:commandButton>
                        
...

<p:dataTable id="table-id" var="data" value="#{ctrl.model}" reflow="true"
 multiViewState="true" draggableColumns="true" selection="#{ctrl.selection}"
 rowKey="#{data.id}" disabledSelection="#{data.disableSel}" paginator="true"
 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
 {PageLinks}   {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50"
 rows="10" rowSelectMode="add" paginatorPosition="bottom" lazy="true"
 sortBy="#{crtl.defaultSort}" stripedRows="true"
>
```

I have search this in the [official documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/components/dataexporter) of prime faces and also in the [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/lazy.xhtml?jfwid=c7f83) official example.

As I am able to export the data with other formats, I think that it could be a problem with the itext dependency (that its obsolete), but if I upgrade that dependency, I get a ClassNotFound runtime error since the import path changes from `com.lowgie` to `com.itext`.

It could be a problem with the configuration? Or it is no longer possible to export data as pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally get the answer. PrimeFaces do not use the itext in its newer versions, you should remove all itext dependencies and use `openpdf` instead:

See the [git repository](https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF) or download the [jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/librepdf/openpdf/1.3.40/openpdf-1.3.40.jar) from [maven central repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.librepdf/openpdf).

Dependency:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.librepdf/openpdf -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.40</version>
</dependency>
```

I get this dependency definition from the [showcase git repository](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/primefaces-showcase/pom.xml). If you need to export the data as a MS file, you can do it with `poi`, see the official pom file to get the full dependency list.

Comment: Yep you got it.